# Login system object: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to start a login session but some of the function can't run without out asking for attributes

Python 3 IDLE application

```
from tkinter import *
import os 

def login_success():
    session() 

def session():
    screen8 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen8.title('Dashboard')
    screen8.geometry('400x400')
    Label(screen8, text = 'Welcome to your dashboard').pack()
    Label(screen8, text = '').pack()
    Button(screen8, = 'Create Notes', command = create_notes).pack()
    Label(screen8, text = '').pack()
    Button(screen8, = 'View Notes').pack()
    Label(screen8, text = '').pack()
    Button(screen8, = 'Delete Notes').pack()
```

```
def session():
    screen8 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen8.title('Dashboard')
    screen8.geometry('400x400')
    Label(screen8, text = 'Welcome to your dashboard').pack()
    Label(screen8, text = '').pack()
    Button(screen8, text = 'Create Notes', command = create_notes).pack()
    Label(screen8, text = '').pack()
    Button(screen8, text = 'View Notes').pack()
    Label(screen8, text = '').pack()
    Button(screen8, text = 'Delete Notes').pack()
```

```
def login_verify():

    username1 = username_verify.get()
    password1 = password_verify.get()
    username_entry1.delete(0, END)
    password_entry1.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            session() #
        else:
            password_not_recognized()

    else:
        user_not_found()

def login():
    global screen2
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("Login")
    screen2.geometry("300x250")

    Label(screen2, text = "Please enter details below to login").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()

    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_entry1
    global password_entry1

    Label(screen2, text = "Username * ").pack()
    #Username Label
    username_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = username_verify)
    username_entry1.pack()
    #space creating
    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()
    Label(screen2, text = "Password * ").pack()
    #Password Label
    password_entry1 = Entry(screen2, textvariable = password_verify)
    password_entry1.pack()

    Label(screen2, text = "").pack()

    Button(screen2, text = "Login", width = 10, height = 1, command = login_verify).pack()
```

What I expect is for another window to open with 3 buttons once I hit login but it comes out to be:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Python Projects\LoginSystem.py", line 78, in login_verify
    session() #
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Python Projects\LoginSystem.py", line 39, in session
    Button(screen8, 'Create Notes').pack() #
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2369, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2295, in __init__
    classes = [(k, v) for k, v in cnf.items() if isinstance(k, type)]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: The last part of your code that actually produced the error is in the `session()` function, which you didn't show.

Comment: Yes, that I didn't include that but I've realized that I made a syntax error. I apologize for the mistakes, I'm new to programming and I need some time to get use to the gist of things